# Downloading MonoDevelop for Unity

Tags: c#

I want to use MonoDevelop with Unity but I have been having problems with downloading it. I did a little of research and experimenting and was wondering if it is even possible to use it with the recent versions of Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Since Unity 2019.2x release, Unity has made it impossible for us to use MonoDevelop-Unity as IDE (with autocompletion & context recognition) by removing the script runtime .NET 3.5 from the editor for all the newer releases.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1520926/how-to-download-monodevelop-and-use-it-in-unity.html

Just use visual studio.